# UIImage not fetching

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm having issues with the `UIImage` crashing my app whenever I run it. I think there is a possibility the images are somehow currupt perhaps. I ran debug and everything seems to run fine up until this line below:

```
let image = UIImage(named: photo!)?.decompressedImage
```

The image key is showing up and everything is running as it should. It is the next line that seems to make the app crash:

```
self.init(caption: caption!, comment: comment!, image: image!)
```

I know I am force unwrapping the image, however I know that the image exists. Do you also agree that maybe the image is corrupt? Is there a way to double check this or perhaps fix it? The images are JPG form.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class Photo {

    class func allPhotos() -> [Photo] {
        var photos = [Photo]()
        if let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Photos", withExtension: "plist") {
            if let photosFromPlist = NSArray(contentsOfURL: URL) {
                for dictionary in photosFromPlist {
                    let photo = Photo(dictionary: dictionary as! NSDictionary)
                    photos.append(photo)
                }
            }
        }

        return photos
    }

    var caption: String
    var comment: String
    var image: UIImage

    init(caption: String, comment: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.caption = caption
        self.comment = comment
        self.image = image
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: NSDictionary)  {
        let caption = dictionary["Caption"] as? String
        let comment = dictionary["Comment"] as? String
        let photo = dictionary["Photo"] as? String
        let image = UIImage(named: photo!)?.decompressedImage
        self.init(caption: caption!, comment: comment!, image: image!)
    }

    func heightForComment(font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let rect = NSString(string: comment).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to post a question about a crash, you must include details about the crash. What is the exact and complete error message? Which line exactly is causing the crash?

Comment: Hi @rmaddy the comment at the breakpoint before the app crashes is 2015-12-16 19:53:28.028 ParseStarterProject-Swift[1831:16761020] -[UINibDecoder CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2dd81d000

Comment: 0x7fd2dd81d000 is the value for the UIImage